# Widget. Activity has leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, android-service

In my `Widget` I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClassForWidget.class); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0); 
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);            
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_widget1, pendingIntent);`
```

And my class `ClassForWidget` already has a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

so, when I click on `Widget`, I have error:

> Activity .ClassForWidget has leaked IntentReceiver
>   .ClassForWidget$MyReceiver@40ebe710  that was originally registered
>   here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: your activity is getting killed before unregistering your receiver

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should register in onResume and unregister in onPause (or onStart and onStop).

```
protected void onPause() {
     if (myReceiver != null){
         unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
         myReceiver = null;
     }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to call `unregisterReceiver()` method in order to un-register the broadcast receiver. I'm not sure how you do it for widgets, but in case its an `Activity`, so we usually need to call this inside `onStop()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unregister the braodcast receiver.

Add this line in your `OnDestroy()` method : `unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);`